# How does GLSL code get “loaded” and “compiled”?

Tags: glsl

I just wanted to find out for sure how GLSL code gets loaded and compiled.

Does the g++ compiler do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, g++/gcc are not involved.

In OpenGL (prior to Vulkan), GLSL code is submitted to the driver as source code strings via a [`glShaderSource`](http://docs.gl/gl4/glShaderSource) call. The driver is fully responsible for compilation, i.e. the driver must provide a built-in GLSL compiler for that GPU architecture. This would typically happen on startup of an app, or during level loading for a game.

With Vulkan, [SPIR-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Portable_Intermediate_Representation) was introduced, which is a device-independent bytecode for shaders (vaguely based on [LLVM IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM#Intermediate_representation)). Now, GLSL code can be pre-compiled to SPIR-V offline using the [shaderc](https://github.com/google/shaderc) toolchain. The developers would do this ahead of time and ship the SPIR-V bytecode with their app. Then at runtime the SPIR-V gets submitted to the Vulkan driver and compiled the rest of the way to GPU machine code.

It's also possible to compile other languages to SPIR-V; for instance, Microsoft's [dxc](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler) compiler for HLSL can optionally output SPIR-V, so you can use this to write Vulkan shaders in HLSL. Also, SPIR-V support has been backported to OpenGL 4.6, so you can now also [load precompiled SPIR-V shaders in OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/SPIR-V).

Comment: Does that mean you could write an app in GL 4.6 and do your shaders in HLSL as well?

Comment: @russ Maybe! I've never tried it, but that may well be possible.

Comment: @russ Yes, it's possible to compile HLSL shaders to GLSL using the [SPIRV-Cross](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Cross) compiler.